# How to use confirm box in php codeigniter inside a function of a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function removeSelectedCategory()
      {
          echo "<script>var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?');         </script>";

          if($r==true)
          {
              some code goes here
          }
```

I have written something like this. Now I want to delete something but I want user to confirm it before deletion. This function is inside controller.

Comment: you **should not** be writing JavaScript in PHP.

Comment: You know, that PHP is server-side and JS is client-side language, right? You can't mix them like that.

Comment: How do I confirm then? Is there any other way?

Comment: Yeah I know but I am confused how to confirm before deletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply provide the JavaScript code when generating the button, link, or whatever needs confirmation. Example:

```
<a href="..." onclick="return confirmDelete();">Delete category</a>
<!-- or -->
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirmDelete();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?');
    }
</script>
```

That way the link / button would be activated only if the user presses 'OK' in the confirmation dialog.